# Testing the relevance of two related variables in the same model

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multicollinearity

I need to test the relevance R of a variable X(1) in Y, and the possible effect that a second variable (θ) has on that same relevance R.

To test it out, I thought of doing a regression (OLS) of Y on X(1) and X(2), where X(2i) = θ(i) * X(1i), 0 < θ < 1, and θ(i) ≠ θ(i+1) ≠ ... ≠ θ(i+N). However, I am concerned that this approach is incorrect and that I am introducing, among other things, collinearity issues into the model.

I also thought about using instrumental variables for X(1), but I am not sure this would be enough to deal with the potential collinearity problems. In this case I would go for a TSLS instead of an OLS.

I have little experience in econometrics and would appreciate any help.